# Merging animation and video at runtime in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanna merge animation and dynamic video i.e video recording taken using camera and also the animation must be shown in the screen when the video is taken . How to do this i simply have no idea from where to start. I have seen video given in the below mentioned site :

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos
```

but here in the above case animation is added at to an existing video but i want to add animation at runtime while the video is recorded and the video should have the animation recorded in it. Hope to get a lead so that i can get started to it..

Comment: i too searching for this...